# Postgres similarity operator with ANY clause - limit for each parameter?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query:

```
SELECT 
  word, 
  similarity(word, 'foo') as "similarity"
FROM words
WHERE word ~* 'foo'
ORDER BY similarity DESC
LIMIT 5
```

which gets called for each word in a search. For example searching for 'oxford university england' would call this query 3 times.

I would now like to write a query which can find similar words to all 3 in one trip to the database, and so far I have something like this:

```
SELECT set_limit(0.4);
SELECT word
FROM words
WHERE word % ANY(ARRAY['foo', 'bar', 'baz']);
```

However, I can't think of a way to say 'give me 5 results for each word'.

Is there a way to write this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unnest the array of words you're searching for and join on the `%` condition instead of applying it in `WHERE`, then number rows for each search word and filter on that number:

```
SELECT subq.search_word
     , subq.word
  FROM (SELECT srch.word as search_word
             , wrd.word 
             , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY srch.word ORDER BY similarity(wrd.word, srch.word) DESC) AS rn
          FROM words wrd
          JOIN UNNEST(ARRAY['foo', 'bar']) as srch(word)
            ON wrd.word % srch.word) subq
 WHERE subq.rn <= 5
```

Comment: I just edited my answer to include ordering by `similarity` in which case I guess `ROW_NUMBER` is still needed.

Comment: thankyou, works great.. the join-unnest-array trick seems great for all sorts of situations!